Is there a way to convert Time messages to Clock messages?
I need to publish a Clock message to a topic, so that Isaac Sim can subscribe to this topic. I saw in the documentation, that a clock message just consists of a Time Message. But if i try to set the sec and nanosec parameter, i get the error "AttributeError: 'Clock' object has no attribute 'sec'". So i can only set these parameters for the time message. But i specifically need a Clock message so is there a way to convert the time message to the a clock message?
Thank you very much!
